# Vertical tabs not rendered correctly under Win XP

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Vertical tabs (in a TPageControl) are not rendered correctly. The text in tab's caption is missing.
Searching the Internet, I have found this is typical to Win XP only and it happens only if themes are applied to those controls. It works on Win Vista and up:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/153186/Vertical-Text-in-a-Tab-Control-Will-Not-Display
http://www.windows-api.com/microsoft/VB-Controls/30463755/trouble-with-tabcontrol.aspx

I am thinking on disabling the themes but not for the whole project, only on TTab or TPageControl but how?
There is any other quick solution?

---

Delphi XE

Comment: Is it XE, or XE2? These things are just better said in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all features of the Windows built-in tab control support themes. Vertically aligned tabs are one such feature.

The code in the first linked article shows how to disable themes for a control. Call [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827.aspx) on it, passing either empty strings or simple spaces for the two string parameters. (The documentation says "empty string," but then demonstrates a one-character string containing a space.)

---

Note that if the VCL control's `RecreateWnd` function is ever called, you'll need to re-apply the theme settings because it will have a new window handle. One way to handle that is to create a descendant control and override `CreateWnd`, which is called after the window handle has been created. That's your best opportunity to apply handle-specific changes to a window.